# "Разлив" или "рóзлив"?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия

Как правильно: "разлив" или "рóзлив"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что слово "рОзлив" является профессиональным жаргоном и употребляется только в виноделии. "Вино на рОзлив". По отношению же ко всему остальному правильно говорить "р**а**злИв".

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже задавалась этим вопросом (работа в алкогольной компании). У нас принято "рОзлив", так что вмешиваться бесполезно и бессмысленно, традиция :)

Answer (score 0):

Ушаков называет слово розлив просторечным вариантом слова разлив.

Разлив вина. Литературная форма слова. Разлив от глагола разлить.

Розлив вин. Слово с тем же самым лексическим значением, но просторечное.

Приставка роз- в русском языке есть. Раз-/рос- являются приставками с чередованием гласных, где "о" употребляется в ударном положении.